PHP not connect to Microsoft Fabric database
I am attempting to connect to a database on Microsoft Fabric, but it will not connect. It does not display any error messages, nor is there anything in the logs. I am at a loss for what the issue could be. If anyone could offer advice, it would be greatly appreciated.
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$server = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.datawarehouse.fabric.microsoft.com';
$database = 'database';
$username = 'fname.lname@company.com'; 
$pwd = 'password';

##################################################
$serverName = "tcp:".$server.",1433";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => $database,
    "Authentication" => "ActiveDirectoryPassword",
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $pwd,
    "Encrypt" => true,
    "TrustServerCertificate" => true
);

##################################################
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if ($conn === false) {
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
}
else {
    echo 'Working';
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}


The PHP version is 8.2

I am using the web server that comes with Laravel 10. For testing, I am not using the Laravel environment, just vanilla PHP. I have also tested on IIS on Windows Server 2016

The ODBC Driver version is 18.3.3.1

PHP SQL Drivers are installed, version 5.12.0.17729 (1/30/24).

I am able to connect to on-prem, Azure, and Azure Synapse databases

I can connect to the Microsoft Fabric database using SSMS

I changed the Authentication to ActiveDirectoryInteractive to see if I could get the MFA window to appear, but it did not

I tried a PDO connection it cause the Laravel webserver to crash. On IIS the browser gives a 500 error.


My gut tells me that something is missing, maybe a driver or something I don’t have enabled. I’m just not sure what it is.

Test the ODBC connection in the ODBC Administrator tool in Windows.  It's often the case that ActiveDirectoryPassword auth flow is blocked by your Entra ID policies.  So you might need to use ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal and provision an App Registration in Entra ID.

So you don't see echo 'Working'; displayed, but you also don't see an error? Is that what you're saying? You weren't too specific about the exact output. What do you see then? Just a blank screen? Is PHP error reporting enabled in your php.ini? (Just in case there's an error which can't be trapped by the directives at the top of the code, that does happen sometimes)

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft I will give the App Registration a try. Thanks!

@ADyson Correct, it does not show anything. I put an echo 'Not Working'; just to make sure there was not other issue. PHP error reporting is enable and there is nothing there. Usually if I can get an error message I can figure where the issue is, but this is not giving me anything to go on.

If you don't see either of those messages though, then the code surely must be failing before that if/else block. Either that or this code you've shown us isn't executing at all. Add some other echo messages earlier in the script and see if they appear when you test it.

Or actually another possibility is that $conn is false but somehow sqlsrv_errors() still returned null. Try var_dump(sqlsrv_errors()); instead of print_r - that will show up null values, where print_r doesn't display anything for null. It would be good to confirm if that's the case or not.

@ADyson the var_dump(sqlsrv_errors()); did show NULL. At least that confirms I am getting nothing.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft I was able to connect using the ODBC Administrator with ActiveDirectoryPassword. I did try the ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal as well in ODBC Administrator. It did not work, but I think there are some permission I need to get worked out.

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft I was able to use the DNS entry I setup to in  ODBC Administrator to connect using odbc in PHP. It is working in my DEV and QC environments, so that give me an option to move forward with my current project. Thanks for your and ADyson's help!
